# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mime' in python/django

Tags: python, django, mime, magic-methods

The first line of this code in .py file returns an error.

```
mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
content_type = mime.from_buffer((data).read(1024))
request.session['content_type'] = content_type
if content_type == 'application/pdf' or content_type == 'application/msword':
    request.session['upload_status'] = "Content type is valid according to (MAGIC)"
```

The error message is
`__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mime'`

I'm using Django 1.4.1 and Python 2.7.3. I have Magic installed. No clue whats going wrong- any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is Magic(mime=True) can you show the `__init__` method of Magic model

Comment: use ctrl-k to display code block.

Answer (score 4):

Just a stab in the dark but The [documentation](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) would suggest that you shouldn't be instantiating the `Magic` class directly.

```
import magic
magic.from_buffer(open("testdata/test.pdf").read(1024))
```

Comment: Actually, now I get the following error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'from_buffer' (even from python command line)

Comment: what version are you using? did you install from github? what methods are available to the object when you type `dir(magic)`?  I just searched for documentation and was going off what i found in github, perhaps you were using another version?

Comment: can you type `magic.version` so we can find out the version and look up the appropriate documentation?

Comment: magic.version said this "<module 'magic.version' from '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/magic/version.pyc'>" but I looked up PKG INFO and here are the version details:    Metadata-Version: 1.0
Name: python-magic
Version: 0.4.1
Summary: File type identification using libmagic
Home-page: http://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Answer (score 1):

The Magic object's constructor does not accept an argument named 'mime'.  I would suggest looking at the doc string with help(magic.Magic); it may give you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

As per suggestions above, if connection to JIRA server fails with error:

```
The error message is __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mime'
```

Then go edit

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py
```

Replace

```
self._magic = magic.Magic(mime=True)
```

with

```
self._magic = magic
```

Then run code like this:

```
from jira.client import JIRA
import magic
...
jira = JIRA(options={'server':'https://jira.server.goes.here'}, basic_auth=(options.username, options.password))
```

I'm using python 2.7.3 with jira-python (http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: This does a great job solving the problem. [Below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59796773/6505499), I've given some more details that should help explain _why_ this change needs to be made.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have another version of `magic`. If I remember correctly from the last time I looked this stuff up, there's a different version that comes with Ubuntu (maybe, there's also something called `filemagic`). The same thing is the case on the out-of-the-box version of Cygwin. That was my case.

I had reinstalled Cygwin and ran into this same issue - two versions of `magic` / `python-magic` / `filemagic` for Python. I looked back here on SO for the solution, but didn't find it quickly. Luckily, I kept notes from before, and the solution that worked for me was:

```sh
$ sudo pip3 uninstall filemagic
$ sudo pip3 install python-magic
```

OR, what worked better on my Cygwin installation:

```sh
$ python -m pip uninstall filemagic
$ python -m pip install python-magic
```

That fixed the problem for me.

As I searched for more on this problem, I came across a very similar solution [here](https://github.com/secrary/SSMA/issues/1) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/save/https://github.com/secrary/SSMA/issues/1)), on github. There is an additional step.

> uninstall filemagic:
>
> `sudo pip3 uninstall filemagic`
>
> uninstall python-magic:
>
> `sudo pip3 uninstall python-magic`

(Possible addition)

`sudo apt-get uninstall python-magic`

> install python-magic:
>
> `sudo pip3 install python-magic`

<s>With a quick search, I couldn't find details of the two versions of `magic`. I just found some comments on threads saying, "You must have the other version of `magic`", or "You must have a different version of `magic`".</s>

**Edit**
I've updated this answer with the `magic` sources. From this, it seems that you might have to do another command before installing `python-magic` with `pip`

`sudo apt-get uninstall python-magic`

as noted above.

---

#### Edit

I found the details about the different versions of `magic` that are floating around.

I have the following three links ( [first](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) , [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25287488/6505499) , [third](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file/+bug/603128) )

Basically, there are two versions going around. The one which has the most support is on PYPI and (it seems to me) is used much more often. It is v.0.4.15 currently (2020-02-19), and its github page is the first link. At that page, you can read the following:

> Name Conflict
>
> There are, sadly, two libraries which use the module name `magic`. Both have been around for quite a while. If you are using this module and get an error using a method like `open`, your code is expecting the other one. Hopefully one day these will be reconciled.

The second version, which seems to cause the most problems, is currently (2020-02-19) v5.25. According to the third link and my own research, this one gets installed when one uses `sudo apt-get install python-magic` on certain versions of Ubuntu. (Look [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/python-magic/1:5.25-2ubuntu1.1) for some possible details from Ubuntu.)

The best explanation of all this is found in the second link. Props to @mhawke for explaining things so well.

Here are archived versions of the links above: [archived first](https://web.archive.org/web/20200220014817/https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic), [archived second](https://web.archive.org/web/20200220014834/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286176/how-to-use-python-magic-5-19-1/25287488), [archived third](https://web.archive.org/web/20200220014850/https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file/+bug/603128), [archived Ubuntu information](https://web.archive.org/web/20200220014930/https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/python-magic/1:5.25-2ubuntu1.1).