# How to use python-magic 5.19-1

Tags: python, python-magic

I need to determine MIME-types from files without suffix in python3 and I thought of python-magic as a fitting solution therefor.
Unfortunately it does not work as described here:
https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/blob/master/README.md

What happens is this:

```
>>> import magic
>>> magic.from_file("testdata/test.pdf")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'from_file'
```

So I had a look at the object, which provides me with the class `Magic` for which I found documentation here:
http://filemagic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide.html

I was surprised, that this did not work either:

```
>>> with magic.Magic() as m:
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ms'
>>> m = magic.Magic()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ms'
>>>
```

I could not find any information about how to use the class `Magic` anywhere, so I went on doing trial and error, until I figured out, that it accepts instances of `LP_magic_set` only for `ms`.
Some of them are returned by the module's methods
`magic.magic_set()` and `magic_t()`.
So I tried to instanciate `Magic` with either of them.
When I then call the `file()` method from the instance, it will always return an empty result and the `errlvl()` method tells me error no. 22.
So how do I use magic anyway?

Comment: Do you have a `magic.py` file in the same directory as the one you launched the python shell from?  The errors you got make it sound like you do (as I just got all your examples working).  One way you can find out is `import inspect` then `inspect.getfile(magic)` and see whether this is the expected file for the `magic` module.

Comment: `>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfile(magic)
'/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/magic.py'`

Comment: Oh wait, you are referring to Ubuntu's `python-magic`.  Yeah that's a completely different package to the one you looked at.  Really though you could take a cursory glance at that file returned by `inspect.getfile` and see that it probably completely differs from [the one on GitHub](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/blob/master/magic.py).

Comment: Another thing, for future reference, is that from the python shell you can call `help(obj)` to get some kind of help from `obj` via the builtin documentations.  So in this case `help(magic)` will also bring up any docstrings and available methods that clearly show that what you got on your system is not the same thing you got the documentation for.

Comment: I already read the module, which was not helpful at all.
It's by the way the Arch-Package.

Comment: As I said, the distro version of the `python-magic` package is NOT the same as the one you linked on github.  They have the exact same name but are completely different.  Heck, even the version number on pypi as linked (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/) is only at 0.4.6.  Also, the distro version is the *bindings* to the magic library, which are NOT the pure native version.  The only help you can get is from realizing your mistake here.

Comment: Got it. My only mistake was to not realize, that these are completely different programs. This does, however, not change the problem I describe in my question: How to use that specific library. Not some completely different stuff from github. Thankfully @mhawke found out how.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that you are confusing different implementations of "python-magic"

You appear to have installed [python-magic-5.19.1](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/), however, you reference firstly the documentation for [python-magic-0.4.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/), and secondly [filemagic-1.6](http://filemagic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I think that you are better off using python-magic-0.4.6 as it is readily available at PYPI and easily installed via `pip` into virtualenv environments.

Documentation for python-magic-5.19.1 is hard to come by, but I managed to get it to work like this:

```
>>> import magic
>>> m=magic.open(magic.MAGIC_NONE)
>>> m.load()
0
>>> m.file('/etc/passwd')
'ASCII text'
>>> m.file('/usr/share/cups/data/default.pdf')
'PDF document, version 1.5'
```

You can also get different magic descriptions, e.g. MIME type:

```
>>> m=magic.open(magic.MAGIC_MIME)
>>> m.load()
0
>>> m.file('/etc/passwd')
'text/plain; charset=us-ascii'
>>> m.file('/usr/share/cups/data/default.pdf')
'application/pdf; charset=binary'
```

or for more recent versions of `python-magic-5.30`

```
>>> import magic
>>> magic.detect_from_filename('/etc/passwd')
FileMagic(mime_type='text/plain', encoding='us-ascii', name='ASCII text')
>>> magic.detect_from_filename('/etc/passwd').mime_type
'text/plain'
```

Comment: Thanks.  Couldn't find the documentation for bindings to that specifically for Python to help this person who can't seem to understand the difference.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation either, just had to read the module source to guess how to use it.

Comment: @MHawke - Thanks for providing a working example with both output formats.  Here is a single example from the libmagic repo (or a fork of it?)  https://github.com/threatstack/libmagic/blob/master/python/example.py         This is only the documentation I could find that presented a workflow of using the module.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion around the two python binding (found a bug report in ubuntu packages by people trying to use the ahupp version of the lib with the standard one.)

Anyway, you can get the same result without open and load: magic.detect_from_filename('your_file').mime_type directly provides the expected answer.

Comment: @MarwanBurelle: Thanks. This answer refers to `file-5.19`, however, `detect_from_filename()` was added in version `file-5.26`. To be strict, the return values are different with one being a string and the other a `namedtuple`, but your suggestion is certainly easier to use if using `file-5.26` or later.

Comment: The libmagic home page seems to be http://darwinsys.com/file/ and there are links to the official repos there. It appears the python is just a wrapper for libmagic(3), so the man page for libmagic may be helpful. For example in python `magic.open(magic.MAGIC_SYMLINK)` is the same as C API `magic_open(MAGIC_SYMLINK)` and the same as the shell command `file -L`.