# extract the text from doc file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

```
import doc2txt
```

I want to extract the string from the document file with Doc2txt it's give the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/doc2text/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import PythonMagick
ImportError: No module named 'PythonMagick'
```

Comment: May be 'PythonMagick' is not installed. pip it or install manually after downloading. then try again

Comment: @latlong Can you tell me how i install PythonMagick in python3 in Ubuntu

Comment: check for 'sudo apt-get install python-pythonmagick' in terminal or search for something like it

Comment: it doesn't work in python3

Comment: In a terminal first enter `pip3 search pythonmagick` to determine the correct name on your repository. Then try and enter `sudo pip3 install actual_name_of_pythonmagick`.

Comment: PythonMagick (0.5)      - Wrapper around GraphicsMagick
PythonMagickWand (0.2)  - Python wrapper for the ImageMagick wand API

Comment: But when i install with sudo pip3 install PythonMagick it shows the error:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PythonMagick (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PythonMagick
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the whl package manually if pip gives you problems.

Whl package:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick

Select the version that you`d like to install

Usage:

`pip install <whl file>`

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal first, then:

```
sudo apt-get install python-magic
```

**or**

```
pip3 install --user python-magic
```

It will install what you need.

You can take a look [here](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) to see how use python-magic

Regards

Comment: istall successfully but didn't work.Installing collected packages: python-magic
Successfully installed python-magic-0.4.15
 import PythonMagic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PythonMagic'

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286176/how-to-use-python-magic-5-19-1